# Exe with tkinter GUI generated by Pyinstaller exe does not work

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I used Pyinstaller to turn my Python script into an standalone executable program.

**My script works when I test it in spyder, but as an exe it does not, and I can't see why.**

#### Program details

My program is composed of :

- A treatment that is a series of functions. It take as input two csv files and return a one-row pandas DataFrame. The last function is called `add_data()`
- A `test()` function that calls add_data(), saves its result in a csv file and notifies the user when the execution is over
- An `execute_test()` function with a **try-except** condition ; **try** calls test() with the user inputs from the GUI, **except** shows an error messagebox.
- A tkinter GUI asking the user to select two csv files + a directory in which test() will save the csv result.

#### Behavior

On spyder, when executing the python script I select the files and directory and it returns the "treatment done" messagebox, so the problem should not come from the script itself.

Pyinstaller successfully builds the exe file. I can open it, the GUI and a command prompt appear ; the entries and buttons work fine.

When launching the treatment after selecting the same files and directory, it only returns the error messagebox, which means the treatment did not execute for some reason.
The only message I got from the prompt was this one :

> C:\Users...\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627:
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable
>   was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.

I don't explicitly import **matplotlib** in my program, and I did not install it in my environment before. I did after this message, but it changed nothing.

Including the whole code of my treatment would be too long, but what I explicitly import within are : **pandas**, **geopandas**, **shapely.geometry**, **tkinter** (see code below). Since I got issues (solved) from this before, it also seems to need **pyproj** when using geopandas

#### Pyinstaller information

If needed, I can provide the whole prompt outputs I got when turning the script into an .exe.
What might be worth mentionning is that I got :

- some **excluding imports** concerning **PySide, PyQt5, gtk, matplotlib, PyQt4, tkinter**
- this **warning**  : `71826 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!`
- And **warnings stating it did not find some DLL** :

```
81853 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
81931 WARNING: lib not found: tbb.dll dependency of ...\mkl_tbb_thread.dll
81978 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
82509 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
82525 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
82556 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
82587 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
82634 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
82712 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
82869 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
83025 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Users\...\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
```

#### Configuration

I work with Miniconda and try to avoid using pip. The configuration of my environment is :

> - **Windows** 10 / **conda** 4.7.10 / **Python** 3.7.3 / **spyder** 3.3.6
> - **pandas** 0.25.0 / **geopandas** 0.5.1 / **pyproj** 2.2.1 / **tk** 8.6.9
> - **numpy** 1.16.4 / **matplotlib** 3.1.1
> - **pyinstaller** 3.5 / **setuptools** 41.0.1 / **pywin32** 224

And lots of other packages and modules that I don't really know (not anaconda though).

I don't even know what title to put exactly because I don't know *where* the error comes from (my guesses would be tkinter, matplotlib or maybe numpy).

I would also like to say I'm quite a beginner programmer and I struggle with the whole packages/modules/imports/dependencies/DLL/compatibility stuff. Still working on it, and I broadly understand most concepts, but I may need detailed explanations about what is going on at this level in order to debug it..
Can someone help ?

#### My code

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Entry,\
filedialog as fd, messagebox

## Functions that will be called by user interaction with the GUI    
def test(file_L, file_T, directory):

    df_test = add_data(file_L, file_T) # calls the previous treatment

    path=str(directory)+'/'+'test_result.csv'
    df_test.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

    messagebox.showinfo("End", "The treatment is done")

def execute_test(inputL, inputT, inputD):
    try:
        return test(inputL.filedir.get(), 
                inputT.filedir.get(), 
                inputD.selecdir.get())
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "The program failed to launch.\n"\
                             "Either the inputs are not correct, or an "\
                             "intern error occured.") 

# Class Button + Entry to select a csv file
class Selection:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.filedir = Entry(master, bd=2)
        self.load_button = Button(master, text="...", bg='yellow',
                                  command=self.loadFile)     

    def loadFile(self):
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(
                filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("all files","*.*"))
                        ) 

        self.filedir.delete(0,"end")
        self.filedir.insert(0, self.filename)

# Class Button + Entry to select a directory
class Directory:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.selecdir = Entry(master, bd=2)
        self.load_button = Button(master, text="...", bg='yellow',
                                  command=self.loadDir)

    def loadDir(self):
        self.dirname = fd.askdirectory()
        self.selecdir.delete(0,"end")
        self.selecdir.insert(0, self.dirname)

# GUI itself
if __name__=='__main__': 

    from functools import partial

    #-----Defining the root
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("+800+400")

    #-----Defining the Frames                   
    f2 = Frame(root)
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2) 
    f2.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)            
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)              
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1) 
    f2.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)      

    f3 = Frame(root)

    #-----Defining the widgets
    TextL = Label(f2, text="Please select file L :")
    L = Selection(f2) 

    TextT = Label(f2, text="Please select file T :")
    T = Selection(f2) 

    TextD = Label(f2, text="Please select the directory in which the result "\
                   "will be saved as a csv :") 
    D = Directory(f2)


    b_validate = Button(f3, text="Execute", bg='cyan',
                        command = partial(execute_test, L, T, D))
    b_exit = Button(f3, text="Exit", bg='red', command = root.destroy)

    #-----Geometry managers    
    f2.pack(expand=True)
    f3.pack(side='right')

    TextL.grid(row=0)
    L.filedir.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    L.load_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w') 

    TextT.grid(row=2)
    T.filedir.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ew')
    T.load_button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')    

    TextD.grid(row=4)  
    D.selecdir.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='ew')
    D.load_button.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='w')

    b_validate.pack(side='left')
    b_exit.pack(side='left')


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Update : I made a mock "add_data()" function to provide a functional GUI to point out the bug ; it simply concatenates the columns of two input csv files and returns the concatenated dataframe. And it works... So it seems the problem comes from an incompatibility between the "treatment" part and pyinstaller. I'll explore this lead functiun by function, and will update this question if I make some progress.

Comment: I can't see the error in your question, all those are warnings and can be ignored. Also, your code doesn't import `pandas`. Run your executable with a CMD and put full error traceback.

Comment: Ok about the warnings. I imported pandas inside the functions, when I needed it. I ran it through a CMD but I don't have get an error traceback ; all I get is the same Matplotlib warning I posted initially. The error message is just the showerror messagebox I programmed so it's "just" that my program doesn't run (I'm investigating function by function right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @M.R. 's advices, useful statements in answer to this question are :

- the warnings can be ignored
- since I got no error traceback in the command prompt, what seems to block is not about the code I posted but *before*

I examinated the details of my treatment function by function. It appears ONE function (at least) makes the whole thing not work.

It's the one that calls geopandas and shapely, and that previously got errors concerning pyproj ; I may open a new question specifically for this matter if I don't succeed in debugging it myself (it will be the same as the question I ask here : for now my python script work, and I can't see why as an exe suddenly it doesn't). In which case I'll link this next question here.

If it can help other desperate programmers, what also helped me in the debugging process was :

- the fact my functions were already separated (which made generating separate exes easier)
- It's useful to have a minimal GUI to turn accompany each function into an exe. If anyone bumps into a similar issue implying user inputs, feel free to use the GUI code I posted as a layout if it saves you time. You'll just have to add your function at the beginning, and change what you call in the `test()` part (where I called `add_data()`.
- I also followed advices from [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It took time but it was worth it.